# Fancybox multiple image gallery within 1 link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple 2 image gallery using JQuery Fancybox.
Upon clicking the small thumbnail image, it loads up a different, larger image, after a short while, i'd like to know how to fade/switch to another DIFFERENT image, and then possibly loop back to the original image after x amount of time. Also, how would I link to these 2 images, that would supposedly be in an array?

```
<a class="fancyYoutube" href="Images/PosterChurchLarge.png"><img src="Images/3DChurchSmall.png"/></a>
```

Is how the image is linked at the moment in html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fancyYoutube").click(function(){
$.fancybox({
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
'width' : 680,
'height' : 395,
'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
'type' : 'swf',
'swf' : {
'wmode' : 'transparent',
'allowfullscreen' : true
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Is the current script for fancybox definitions. (Bare in mind I have a video displayed through fancybox, which is why the features are swf based.)

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Comment: Version 1.3.4, i'll edit the extra links in

Comment: Fancybox already has image gallery options to make it easy to cycle through photos. But doesn't have a slide show option unless you use **Ver 2**

Comment: That is what i'm trying to get, it to just cycle through two images, however i dont know how to link both into the same anchor

Comment: I gave you an answer on how to do the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example and working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AwRk2/1/  Ver 1.3.4

HTML code for 3 photos that will cycle through. Just use 2 instead of 3 photos.

```
<a rel="example_group" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">
        <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg" />
    </a>

    <a rel="example_group" title="" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2591/4135665747_3091966c91.jpg">
        <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2591/4135665747_3091966c91_m.jpg" />
    </a>

    <a rel="example_group" title="" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2561/4048285842_90b7e9f8d1.jpg">
        <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2561/4048285842_90b7e9f8d1_m.jpg" />
    </a>
```

Then this is the fancybox code used to do it.

```
$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'titlePosition'     : 'over',
        'cyclic'            : true,
        'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
            return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!
I had just gotten the html bit correct by myself and tested it with some default fancybox definitions.

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend looking into ver 2 soon when you have time. Has some more options for other things. good luck.

Comment: Apologies to bother you again, is there any way this version of fancybox supports autoplay? So that after say 2 seconds the image changes to the next one along?

Comment: Give this post a try. this person recoded 1.3.4 to have a slide show. Check the whole post. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/JdxINEhhLQc That's all I can suggest short of ver 2.